# getting BadTokenException in dialog.show()

Tags: android

I am trying to write a small application in Android. 
I got the following error in dialog.show(). But it is not replicating.I do not have any clue why it is happening. Please help. May be the 
exception is cleaning up something and the next time the application 
works fine.Code snippet is below

```
private ProgressDialog pd = null;

public AsyncTaskAllCurrency(Context ctx,
        IAsyncTaskCompletedListner<CurrencyReturnPojo> listner) {
    this.context = ctx;
    this.callback = listner;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    pd = createProgressDialog(context, "Loading Please wait...");
    pd.show();
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(CurrencyReturnPojo result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    callback.onTaskComplete(result);
    pd.dismiss();
}

private ProgressDialog createProgressDialog(Context context, String msg) {
    ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
    progressDialog.setMessage(msg);
    progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
    // progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
    return progressDialog;
}
```

this exception i got

```
    android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token 
        android.os.BinderProxy@41c3bda0 is not valid; is your activity running?
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:567)
  at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:246)
  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
  at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:281)
 com. 
 zyksa.converter.pro.AsyncTaskSingleCurrency.onPreExecute(AsyncTaskSingleCurrency.java:
  42)
  at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:586)
   at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:534)
            com.
zyksa.converter.pro.GeneralConverterActivity.singleCurrencyAsynctaskCaller(GeneralConve
 rterActivity.java:1316)
   at 
 com.
zyksa.
converter.pro.GeneralConverterActivity.access$17(GeneralConverterActivity.java:1299) 
com.zyksa.converter.
 pro.GeneralConverterActivity
$FetchAllCurrencyTaskCompletedListner.onTaskComplete
(GeneralConverterActivity.java:1339)
at com.zyksa.converter.
pro.GeneralConverterActivity$
FetchAllCurrencyTaskCompletedListner.onTaskComplete(GeneralConverterActivity.java:1)
at com.zyksa.
converter.pro.AsyncTaskAllCurrency.onPostExecute(AsyncTaskAllCurrency.java:40)
  at com.zyksa.converter
 .pro.AsyncTaskAllCurrency.onPostExecute(AsyncTaskAllCurrency.java:1)
   at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
  at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
  at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I found my issue finally. Unfortunately i commented one line of code i.e.,progressDialog.setCancelable(false);. After uncommented the line of code it is working fine with out issues.

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe posting the logs of the error would help us a bit?

Comment: This exception occurs mostly because of bad context reference. Maybe the Activity context which you passed to create Progress dialog was garbage collected.

Comment: your context is incorrect. what context do you use to create your dialog?

Comment: I used the context like this- private Context context; can anyone please help me to sort out this issue

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

private ProgressDialog pd = null;

```
public AsyncTaskAllCurrency(Context ctx,
        IAsyncTaskCompletedListner<CurrencyReturnPojo> listner) {
    this.context = ctx;
    this.callback = listner;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    pd = new ProgressDialog(ctx);
    pd.setMessage("Loading Please Wait..");
    pd.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER); 
    pd.show();
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(CurrencyReturnPojo result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    callback.onTaskComplete(result);
    pd.dismiss();
}


}
```

Comment: thanks for your quick reply but i got BadToken Exception, may be it is the effect of context which i have given and how can i solve that

Comment: In my snippet I have already given your updated code in another method called createProgressDialog(), can any another option that we have to modify?